# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't know there's a battery

Tags: 12.04, laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The battery indicator in Unity panel not showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133379/the-battery-indicator-in-unity-panel-not-showing-up)

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspire 5553. It's the first time I've used Linux for more than 4 years so I don't really know what I'm doing. The installation went almost perfectly; Internet connections and graphics were all configured fine (which is more than I can say for the Windows 7 I've just installed on a dual boot).

However, when I unplug the power supply, there is no battery indicator displayed. In the power settings, there is only one column; I've seen screenshots indicating that I should see two columns, one for "On battery power" and one for "When plugged in". There is also no field "When power is critically low".

I can use the laptop on battery power, but it just keeps running on full power until it suddenly switches off. It seems like the OS doesn't "know" it's on a laptop.

I installed Windows 7 yesterday on dual boot and that configured the power supply perfectly (unlike most of the other hardware).

I reinstalled 12.04 this morning and the problem persists.

The problem is there in both Unity and Gnome.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/164991/25082) is the answer you may be looking for.  From the duplicate indicated by Eliah Kagan

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf Editor via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

or using the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Then perform the action indicated in the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this option was already set this way. I think the problem is at a 'lower level'.