# Power Indicator gone missing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: indicator

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit for quite some time on Acer Aspire One AOD255 netbook and today I found out that power indicator icon is missing from unity panel. Also, I didnot get any low power notification and my laptop just turned off instead of hibernating. The indicator is being displayed on login screen.

---

`upower` output:

```
ali@ali-AOD255:~$ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun Jul 21 20:26:31 2013 (773 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             no

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                AL10A31
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun Jul 21 20:39:02 2013 (22 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              2.9082 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         18.1263 Wh
    energy-full-design:  24.42 Wh
    energy-rate:         9.8568 W
    voltage:             10.802 V
    time to empty:       17.7 minutes
    percentage:          16.0441%
    capacity:            74.2273%
    technology:          lithium-ion
  History (charge):
    1374421111  16.044  discharging
  History (rate):
    1374421142  9.857   discharging
    1374421111  9.446   discharging
    1374421080  9.291   discharging

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.20
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   yes
  on-battery:      yes
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

`dmesg` output:

```
ali@ali-AOD255:~$ dmesg | grep -i acpi
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f577000-0x000000007f5befff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f5ec000-0x000000007f5fefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 000fe020 00024 (v02 ACRSYS)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 7f5fe120 00064 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001      01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 7f5fd000 000F4 (v04 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 7f5f1000 08D6F (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 7f584000 00040
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 7f5fc000 00038 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 7f5fb000 00078 (v02 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 7f5fa000 0003C (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 7f5f0000 00176 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BOOT 7f5ef000 00028 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000001 1025 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 7f5ed000 00655 (v01  PmRef    CpuPm 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.000000] ACPI: WDAT 7f5ec000 00194 (v01 INSYDE INSYDE   00000001 MSFT 01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x00] disabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x04] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.012225] ACPI: Core revision 20121018
[    0.108314] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x7f577000-0x7f5befff] (294912 bytes)
[    0.111405] ACPI: bus type pci registered
[    0.114917] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.114917] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.114917] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.114917] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.119212] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
[    0.123126] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.127354] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.128403] ACPI: SSDT 7f4b7790 00708 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Ist 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.129765] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.129772] ACPI: SSDT   (null) 00708 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Ist 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.130144] ACPI: SSDT 7f4b5690 00646 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20051117)
[    0.131056] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.131063] ACPI: SSDT   (null) 00646 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20051117)
[    0.131111] ACPI: SSDT 7f4b6d90 0015F (v01  PmRef    ApIst 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.132907] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.132915] ACPI: SSDT   (null) 0015F (v01  PmRef    ApIst 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.132945] ACPI: SSDT 7f4b6f10 0008D (v01  PmRef    ApCst 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.133181] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.133187] ACPI: SSDT   (null) 0008D (v01  PmRef    ApCst 00003000 INTL 20051117)
[    0.133218] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.133218] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.133218] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.271632] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (on)
[    0.272548] ACPI: EC: GPE = 0x19, I/O: command/status = 0x66, data = 0x62
[    0.272873] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.272885] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.273675] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.273683] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
[    0.289605] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.EXP1._PRT]
[    0.289745] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.EXP2._PRT]
[    0.290078]  pci0000:00: Requesting ACPI _OSC control (0x1d)
[    0.290538]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC control (0x1c) granted
[    0.292537] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12)
[    0.292688] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 *10 11 12)
[    0.292833] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12)
[    0.292978] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12)
[    0.293123] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12) *0, disabled.
[    0.293269] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12) *0, disabled.
[    0.293415] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12) *0, disabled.
[    0.293572] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12) *0, disabled.
[    0.296717] ACPI: bus type scsi registered
[    0.296747] ACPI: bus type usb registered
[    0.296747] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.322754] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.322786] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
[    0.384628] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.384712] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
[    0.384819] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.385054] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
[    0.385140] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
[    0.385215] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
[    0.385352] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.385522] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SYN1b1c SYN1b00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.385863] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
[    0.385869] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    0.385876] PnPBIOS: Disabled by ACPI PNP
[    1.272199] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (off-line)
[    1.272363] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.272469] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    1.272616] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.272735] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    1.272854] ACPI: Fan [FAN] (on)
[    1.272990] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[    1.408392] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THRM] (59 C)
[    2.068247] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[   26.088969] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras
[   26.089283] acer_wmi: Brightness must be controlled by acpi video driver
[   26.787802] ACPI Warning: 0x00000428-0x0000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMBA 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   26.787822] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   26.787832] ACPI Warning: 0x00000530-0x0000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   26.787845] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   26.787851] ACPI Warning: 0x00000500-0x0000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   26.787864] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   28.855074] acpi device:27: registered as cooling_device3
[   28.855507] ACPI: Video Device [OVGA] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
```

Comment: I think ACPI isn't working properly and it's not just the display of an icon. Please include the output of `upower -d` run in a terminal in your question, also `dmesg | grep -i acpi` might give some hints.

Comment: How to post output as long posts cannot be done here. Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: **Edit** your question, copy&paste it in, then use proper formatting (`<$>` in the editor toolbar). We don't post comments to provide more information - on a Q&A site you work on your question by improving the question itself. :)

Comment: This is the best I can do..

Comment: ACPI detection looks good from the command line. This shows me that your hardware is recognized properly and it is indeed just a displaying issue about the power icon then. (I'm lost from here.)

Comment: Might want to doublecheck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133379/the-battery-indicator-in-unity-panel-not-showing-up

Comment: I've tried all that without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made another user account account and loging into that account solved the problem and battery indicator has returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to checked if you may have it set to show the indicator to "Never".

Just go to "System Settings..." -> "power"

See in this picture

[image]

Comment: Already did that. Its on "When battery is present"